# Remove from a list (or DataFrame) substrings contained the same list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, iteration

I have a list of lists (let's call it IDlist): what i want to do is removing the elements (lists) of IDlist that are "substrings" of other elements (other lists) of IDlist.

It is not necessary to use lists, also Pandas objects are good if it's easier.

The only ways i've come up with work only partially (only in specific scenarios) therefore they are useless.
I really don't know how make the list work on "itself".

Here is a part of the dataset. For example, lines 61,62,63,64. 61,62 and 64 are substrings of 63, so i should keep only the line 63.

```
56 ['2588446634610274688', '2588446634612110336']
57 ['348020242217448576', '348020448377061376', '348020482735930112']
58 ['565983471644073472', '565989347158652288']
59 ['4912580642524184960', '4912898156569562624']
60 ['318121222523445376', '318121256883850112']
61 ['356731363606425856', '357478894075788928', '357479272034582528']
62 ['356731363606425856', '357478894075788928', '357479272034582528']
63 ['356731363606425856', '356731363608936576', '357478894075788928', '357479272034582528']
64 ['356731363606425856', '356731363608936576', '357478894075788928']
65 ['2512629230496996992', '2512629230497166848']
```

Print command output:

```
>>> print(templist)
[['318121222523445376', '318121256883850112'], ['356731363606425856', '357478894075788928', '357479272034582528'], ['356731363606425856', '357478894075788928', '357479272034582528'], ['356731363606425856', '356731363608936576', '357478894075788928', '357479272034582528'], ['356731363606425856', '356731363608936576', '357478894075788928'], ['2512629230496996992', '2512629230497166848']]
```

Comment: please provide a reproducible example as code, not image

Comment: @mozway you are right, I've fixed it!

Comment: The exact type of your object is still ambiguous. If a list provide the content of `print(your_list)`, if a DataFrame: `df.to_dict()`, right now this is not a valid python object

Comment: @mozway sorry, i'm not expert, i've added the print output, i hope it's clear! If not, please tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found is to iterate through IDlist with nested loops and pop subset list from a copy of IDlist

```
IDlist = [['2588446634610274688', '2588446634612110336'],
          ['348020242217448576', '348020448377061376', '348020482735930112'],
          ['565983471644073472', '565989347158652288'],
          ['4912580642524184960', '4912898156569562624'],
          ['318121222523445376', '318121256883850112'],
          ['318121222523445376', '318121256883850112'],
          ['356731363606425856', '357478894075788928', '357479272034582528'],
          ['356731363606425856', '357478894075788928', '357479272034582528'],
          ['356731363606425856', '356731363608936576', '357478894075788928', '357479272034582528'],
          ['356731363606425856', '356731363608936576', '357478894075788928'],
          ['2512629230496996992', '2512629230497166848'], ]


def is_subset(a, b):
    for i in a:
        if i not in b:
            return False
    return True


new_IDlist = IDlist.copy()


for id_j, j in enumerate(IDlist):
    for id_k, k in enumerate(IDlist):
        if id_k == id_j:
            continue
        if len(k) < len(j):
            if is_subset(k, j):
                for _, l in enumerate(new_IDlist):
                    if k == l:
                        new_IDlist.pop(_)
                        break
        else:
            if is_subset(j, k):
                cnt = 0
                for _, l in enumerate(new_IDlist):
                    if k == l:
                        if cnt:
                            new_IDlist.pop(_)
                        else:
                            cnt += 1
```

**Output**

```
['2588446634610274688', '2588446634612110336']
['348020242217448576', '348020448377061376', '348020482735930112']
['565983471644073472', '565989347158652288']
['4912580642524184960', '4912898156569562624']
['318121222523445376', '318121256883850112']
['356731363606425856', '356731363608936576', '357478894075788928', '357479272034582528']
['2512629230496996992', '2512629230497166848']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the current list is a subset or superset of all other lists with a nested loop. Let's see:

```py
def exclude_subsets(data):
    cleaned_data = set(map(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)), data))
    
    superset_list = []
    for k,i in enumerate(cleaned_data):
        for l,j in enumerate(cleaned_data):
            if k != l:
                superset_list.append([k,l,set(i).issuperset(j)])
    subset_ids = list(map(lambda x: x[1], filter(lambda x: x[2], superset_list)))
    return [list(i) for k,i in enumerate(cleaned_data) if k not in subset_ids]
```

```py
data = [['2588446634610274688', '2588446634612110336'],
          ['348020242217448576', '348020448377061376', '348020482735930112'],
          ['565983471644073472', '565989347158652288'],
          ['4912580642524184960', '4912898156569562624'],
          ['318121222523445376', '318121256883850112'],
          ['318121222523445376', '318121256883850112'],
          ['356731363606425856', '357478894075788928', '357479272034582528'],
          ['356731363606425856', '357478894075788928', '357479272034582528'],
          ['356731363606425856', '356731363608936576', '357478894075788928', '357479272034582528'],
          ['356731363606425856', '356731363608936576', '357478894075788928'],
          ['2512629230496996992', '2512629230497166848']]


print(exclude_subsets(data))
>>
[['565983471644073472', '565989347158652288'],
 ['4912580642524184960', '4912898156569562624'],
 ['356731363606425856','356731363608936576','357478894075788928','357479272034582528'],
 ['2588446634610274688', '2588446634612110336'],
 ['348020242217448576', '348020448377061376', '348020482735930112'],
 ['2512629230496996992', '2512629230497166848'],
 ['318121222523445376', '318121256883850112']]
```